# How to check if username in one table and medicalcenter in another table is correct, then it will login?

Tags: c#, forms, authentication, combobox

I have two tables called DOCTOR and MEDICALCENTRE. I made doctorID as primary key in DOCTOR table, and mcID primary key in MEDICALCENTRE. I Created the relationship between them too. I have already done the login using username and password code. But now I still need a additional thing which is the mcCentre field which exist in MEDICALCENTRE table.

The mcCentre will be in a combobox.  I have already done putting in datas from the database into the combobox. If either dusername, dpassword, or mcCentre is wrong, it will not let you login. It must be the correct dusername, dpassword and mcCentre, then the form will let you login.

So I think that what I need to do is to add codes to check whether dusername or mcCentre field is correct. What I want to achieve is for e.g., If I login with Jack, and Tan Tock Seng and the correct password, it will let me login, but if I login with Jack and Woodland and the correct password, login will failed as Jack doesn't exist in Woodland mcCentre. How do I do that?

Please see image and login code below.

[image: page_one which is the login form]
[image: doctor table]
[image: medicalcentre table]
[image: error]

```
public page_one()
{
    InitializeComponent();
    Fillcombo();
}


void Fillcombo()
{
    string strConnectionString = ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings["projectConnection"].ConnectionString;
    string Query = "select * from MEDICALCENTRE ;";
    SqlConnection conDataBase = new SqlConnection(strConnectionString);
    SqlCommand cmdDataBase = new SqlCommand(Query, conDataBase);
    SqlDataReader myReader;


    try
    {

        conDataBase.Open();
        myReader = cmdDataBase.ExecuteReader();

        while (myReader.Read())
        {
            string sName = myReader["mcCentre"].ToString();
            comboBox1.Items.Add(sName);
        }
    }
    catch (Exception ex)
    {

    }


}

private void btnLogin_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    //retrieve connection information info from App.config
    string strConnectionString = ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings["projectConnection"].ConnectionString;
    //STEP 1: Create connection
    SqlConnection myConnect = new SqlConnection(strConnectionString);
    //STEP 2: Create command
    string strCommandtext = "SELECT dUsername, dPassword from DOCTOR";
    // Add a WHERE Clause to SQL statement
    strCommandtext += "   WHERE dUsername=@dname AND dPassword=@dpwd;";
    SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand(strCommandtext, myConnect);
    cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@dname", textUsername.Text);
    cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@dpwd", txtPassword.Text);



    try
    {
        // STEP 3: open connection and retrieve data by calling ExecuteReader
        myConnect.Open();
        // STEP 4: Access Data
        SqlDataReader reader = cmd.ExecuteReader();


        while (reader.Read()) //For Doctor
        {
            if (MessageBox.Show("Login Successful") == DialogResult.OK)
            {
                timer1.Enabled = true;
                return;
            }
        }



        //STEP 5: close connection
        reader.Close();
        MessageBox.Show("Invalid username or password");
    }
    catch (SqlException ex)
    {

    }
    finally
    {
        //STEP 5: close connection
        myConnect.Close();
    }
}
```

This is my current code. I removed the catch like what steve have told me. And Now it gave me error Incorrect syntax near the keyword 'INNER' when the login button is clicked. Which means that INNER line of code is wrong? See last image also.

```
void Fillcombo()
        {
            string strConnectionString = ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings["projectConnection"].ConnectionString;
            string Query = "select * from MEDICALCENTRE ;";
            SqlConnection conDataBase = new SqlConnection(strConnectionString);
            SqlCommand cmdDataBase = new SqlCommand(Query, conDataBase);
            SqlDataReader myReader;


            try
            {

                conDataBase.Open();
                myReader = cmdDataBase.ExecuteReader();

                while (myReader.Read())
                {
                    string sName = myReader["mcCentre"].ToString();
                    comboBox1.Items.Add(sName);
                }
            }
            catch (Exception ex)
            {

            }


        }

        private void btnLogin_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            //retrieve connection information info from App.config
            string strConnectionString = ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings["projectConnection"].ConnectionString;
            //STEP 1: Create connection
            SqlConnection myConnect = new SqlConnection(strConnectionString);
            //STEP 2: Create command
            string strCommandtext = "SELECT dUsername, dPassword from DOCTOR";
            // Add a WHERE Clause to SQL statement
            //strCommandtext += "   WHERE dUsername=@dname AND dPassword=@dpwd;";
            strCommandtext = " INNER JOIN MEDICALCENTRE ON DOCTOR.mcId = MEDICALCENTRE.mcId";
            // Add a WHERE Clause to SQL statement
            strCommandtext += "   WHERE dUsername=@dname AND dPassword=@dpwd AND mcCentre = @mcname;";            
            SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand(strCommandtext, myConnect);
            cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@dname", textUsername.Text);
            cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@dpwd", txtPassword.Text);
            cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@mcname", comboBox1.ToString());




            try
            {
                // STEP 3: open connection and retrieve data by calling ExecuteReader
                myConnect.Open();
                // STEP 4: Access Data
                SqlDataReader reader = cmd.ExecuteReader();


                while (reader.Read()) //For Doctor
                {
                    if (MessageBox.Show("Login Successful") == DialogResult.OK)
                    {
                        timer1.Enabled = true;
                        return;
                    }
                }



                //STEP 5: close connection
                reader.Close();
                MessageBox.Show("Invalid username or password");


            }

            finally
            {
                //STEP 5: close connection
                myConnect.Close();
            }
        }


        private void page_one_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            pbLoading.Maximum = 100;
        }
```

Comment: From your database design, it appears that a doctor can only be associated with one medical centre - in which case, why offer the drop-down at all? Why not just look it up after login?

Comment: I'm with @Damien_The_Unbeliever on this one. Never give your users a choice where they actually don't have any.

Comment: @Damien hmm I will think about it. Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The NullReferenceException in your case (as shown in the last image) is caused by the **combobox1.SelectedItem.ToString()** conversion.

In your watch window, it is partially visible that **combobox1.SelectedItem** is null, so calling the **ToString()** method on a null value results in a **NullReferenceException**

You could resolve this problem using the Text property of this combobox changing your last parameter construction with

```
cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@mcname", combobox1.Text)
```

I think that this happens because you have a combobox with `Style = DropDown`. In this way the user can type the name of the **MedicalCenter** but this doesn't result in a **SelectedItem** property set.

Comment: Ok the error is gone, but I still can't login whether if i provide wrong details or correct details, it gives me this at the outputbox when i clicked the login button. A first chance exception of type 'System.Data.SqlClient.SqlException' occurred in System.Data.dll. See the 4th image. Does the code that Mr Alexander gave me is wrong? for that INNER JOIN line of code. @Steve

Comment: Coul you replace that image and its tiny text with an actual dump of your code in the btnLogin_Click event? Did you know? But we (old people) have no more the eyes for that.

Comment: The code seems correct. Can you find more details about the exception? (StackTrace, Details...) etc on the Visual Studio Message with the exception

Comment: I suggest also to remove the empty catch clause in the btnLogin_Click event. This catch effectively hides the exception when it is raised. For example, suppose that you have a problem when opening the connection. The catch hides the exception and the finally call the close on an not open connection....

Comment: `strCommandtext = " INNER JOIN MEDICALCENTRE ON DOCTOR.mcId = MEDICALCENTRE.mcId";` should be `strCommandtext += "....`, what I was saying about not having a good eye?

Comment: LOLS. thanks, careless haha. But I put in username as jack, password as test and mcCentre as Tan Tock Seng and it gives me invalid username and password. Jack exist in tan tock seng mcCentre so it should let me login. @Steve

Comment: In your last version there is an error adding the parameter for the combobox1. Should be `cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@mcname", comboBox1.Text);`

Answer (score 1):

1) You should use different passwords on different accounts, or else you can't really test whether login is successful. Use test, 123, test3 etc.

2) Your foreign key is wrong, as You will figure out when trying to add multiple doctors to one clinic.

3) Here's your fish:

```
string strCommandtext = "SELECT dUsername, dPassword from DOCTOR";
strCommandtext = " INNER JOIN MEDICALCENTRE ON DOCTOR.mcId = MEDICALCENTRE.mcId";
// Add a WHERE Clause to SQL statement
strCommandtext += "   WHERE dUsername=@dname AND dPassword=@dpwd AND mcCentre = @mcname;";

cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@mcname", comboBox.selectedItem.ToString());
```

Comment: Your second point is wrong. The relationshio is right if we say: _A doctor works at one and only one medical center. A medical center has 1 or many doctors working there._ In this case the FK is (as now) on the DOCTOR table for the MEDICALCENTER id. It is different if we say: _A doctor works in zero or MANY medicalcenters._ In this case we have a MANY to MANY and a new table is required.

Comment: @Alexander thanks for the fast reply. oh my foreign key is wrong is it, I will solved it after solving this then. I edited the codes alr using yours.  I have error like the attached image when i click the login button when nothing is typed. and have error of this at the outputbox (A first chance exception of type 'System.Data.SqlClient.SqlException' occurred in System.Data.dll) if i select a medicalcenter and clicked the login button.

Comment: @Steve: Correct me if I'm wrong, but the second image looks to me like "DOCTOR.doctorID is the foreign key", where it should be "DOCTOR.mcID is the foreign key".

Comment: Yes I think so, probably too much screenshoots

Comment: If you are referring to the NullReferenceException then change the line to `cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@mcname", combobox1.Text)`

Answer (score 0):

In your database structure

```
select count(*) 
from MEDICALCENTRE 
WHERE mcID in (select mcID from DOCTOR where dUsername = @dname AND dPassword = @dpwd)
```

I think this query will return count > 1 if login successful

But if each doctor has only one MEDICALCENTRE then , I think you need only one table.

Comment: I like the subquery approach, but it is wrong `(select mcID from DOCTOR....)`. Also the advice to add a doctorID to the medicalcenter table will be of no help if we have many doctors in a medicalcenter. A new table is required in this case to hold the MANY to MANY relationship

Comment: @Steve Yes ,You are correct,  if we have many doctors in a medicalcenter,  A new table is required. Edited my answer. Thanks